Quarkus getting started `GLIBC_2.33' not found when trying to run Dockerfile.native_micro
Trying out quarks went through creating your first app get-started, saw it produced the 4 different Dockerfiles for you.
The native being one of the features of quarkus I wanted to try those so followed the instructions in each of the files.  All the steps worked until I went to run the Dockerfile.native/.native-micro then failed with the following error.
./mvnw package -Dnative
podman build -f src/main/docker/Dockerfile.native-micro -t quarkus/order-processor-dapr .
podman run -i --rm -p 8080:8080 quarkus/order-processor-dapr
...
./application: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by ./application)
./application: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by ./application)
./application: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by ./application)

considering this is straight out of the box tutorial, I'm wondering what I'm missing or if something isn't right with the setup.  I can't imagine Podman being the problem for that particular error.
Dockerfile native
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.9
WORKDIR /work/
RUN chown 1001 /work \
    && chmod "g+rwX" /work \
    && chown 1001:root /work
COPY --chown=1001:root target/*-runner /work/application

EXPOSE 8080
USER 1001

ENTRYPOINT ["./application", "-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0"]


Hwo do you build the native image? It is generally recommended that if we want to run the native image in a container, we should also build it in a container. I would recommend using quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-mandrel-builder-image to build and quay.io/quarkus/quarkus-distroless-image to run the naitve image.

thanks, the commands I used are in question.  I got those commands from the Dockerfile comments that quarks produced when I created the project.

Did the naitve build run in a container, or did it run on your machine?

I was able to reproduce the issue when the native build runs on my host, not in a contianer. When i built in a container, everything works as expected. If it did not build in a container for you, can you re-run the build with ./mvnw -Dnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true clean package?

thank you for the good direction, this command finally worked for me: quarkus build --native -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true -Dquarkus.native.container-runtime=podman -Dquarkus.native.native-image-xmx=3G -Dquarkus.container-image.build=true makes sense that I would want to build it in the container I want to run it in, surprised the initial instructions in the docker files don't work out of the box.  put an answer down, I'll give you credit.  thx again

I also found this page which helped: https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image and installed Mandrel which you suggested

During native compilation, the native-image will link against dynamic libraries. The library versions on our local machine might be different from the versions used in, for example, the micro image. Therefore, it is best practice to run the naitve-image compilation in a container when we want to run it in a container later on.
We can explicitly instruct quarkus to build the native image in a container by setting -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true:
./mvnw \
  -Dnative \
  -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true \
   clean package

For more information, I recommend reading the guide on native compilation at quarkus.io. For advanced topics on native compilation, please see section "Related content" on the bottom of the page. It links to related articles.
